# Minimum number of patches needed to find color correction matrix (CCM)

Tags: opencv, colors, computer-vision

`The chart should have at least 9 distinct color patches for 3×3 CCMs (which are generally recommended). Excellent results can usually be achieved with the inexpensive, widely-available 24-patch X-Rite Colorchecker.` https://www.imatest.com/docs/color-correction-matrix-ccm/

Is there a particular reason that we need at least 9 patches?

I am asking this because I am working on a computer vision project that uses a color card with only 4 patches. I followed the tutorial here https://blog.francium.tech/using-machine-learning-for-color-calibration-with-a-color-checker-d9f0895eafdb?gi=2f504b4aa5b4. But none of the method work, make me wonder is there a minimum requirement to find the CCM?

I couldn't find any research to discuss this question, so I came here for help. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why did you tag this "OpenCL"?

Comment: it shd be opencv. Thanks/.